# Compute Hausdorff distance for 3D numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, computer-vision, image-segmentation

Imagine we are under a segmentation problem that has 5 classes (0, 1, 2, 3, 4). Considering that we have the following 3D mask volumes (A.K.A. 3D numpy arrays):

```
# Ground truth mask
y_true = np.array([[[2, 1, 4], [0, 1, 1], [2, 1, 0]],
                    [[2, 2, 2], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]],
                    [[2, 4, 4], [2, 1, 4], [2, 1, 1]]])

# Predicted mask
y_pred = np.array([[[2, 0, 4], [0, 2, 1], [2, 0, 0]],
                    [[2, 4, 0], [0, 1, 2], [0, 4, 1]],
                    [[2, 0, 4], [1, 1, 4], [2, 2, 1]]])
```

How can I compute the Hausdorff distance between them? I've looked into [Monai's](https://docs.monai.io/en/stable/_modules/monai/metrics/hausdorff_distance.html) implementation however couldn't figure out the meaning of the `compute_hausdorff_distance` output.

I implemented a one-hot encoder, since Monai requires the inputs to be one-hot encoded.

```
def one_hot_encode(array):
    return np.eye(5)[array].astype(dtype=int)
```

Now we have that:

```
# Ground truth mask
y_true = [[[[0 0 1 0 0]
   [0 1 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 0 1]]

  ...

  [[1 0 0 0 0]
   [0 1 0 0 0]
   [0 1 0 0 0]]]


# Predicted mask
y_pred = [[[[0 0 1 0 0]
   [1 0 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 0 1]]

  ...

  [[0 0 1 0 0]
   [0 0 1 0 0]
   [0 1 0 0 0]]]]
```

The output of Monai's implementation is:

```
>>> compute_hausdorff_distance(one_hot_encode(y_pred), one_hot_encode(y_true), include_background=True)
>>> [[1.         1.         1.        ]
 [2.         1.41421356 3.        ]
 [2.23606798 1.         1.        ]]
```

Looking at it I can understand it is computing the euclidean distance. It looks like it is looking at labels as positions, but should't the output be of shape `3x3x3`just like the masks?

Also, [Scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.directed_hausdorff.html) implementation only works for 2D masks/arrays. Would it be right to compute the Hausdorff distance slice-wise, i.e., slice by slice, and afterwards average all the slice Hausdorff distances obtained? Or does this approach violates the Hausdorff distance principle for 3D data?

Comment: @Janikas - the scipy implementation uses 2d arrays of _coordinates_. so that would work for your problem

Comment: @jkr thank you for you help! :) So every one-hot encoded label corresponds to a coordinate?

Comment: Following the documentation for the `HausdorffDistanceMetric` the expected array layout is 'BCHW[D]' (batch, channel (one hot), height, width, depth). After changing *one_hot_encode* to `return np.eye(5)[array].astype(dtype=int).transpose(3,0,1,2)[None]`, `compute_hausdorff_distance(one_hot_encode(y_pred), one_hot_encode(y_true), include_background=True)` yields a distance for each class: `tensor([[1.7321, 1.4142, 1.4142,    nan, 1.7321]], dtype=torch.float64)`. I'm not able to verify if that is the desired result.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I love you!!! Thank you so much :)